# How to calculate multiple bands at the same time R raster?

Tags: r, if-statement, raster, r-raster, rgdal

I am trying to calculate a 72 bands raster. If the first 36 bands value (near infrared band) is greater than the latter 36 bands value (shortwave infrared band), assign it 0; if not then proceed on the following function. I tried other ways of writing it (basically the same logic) and the same errors show up. This is the function I wrote:

```
raster_stack <- stack("NIR.bin", "SWIR.bin")
#ndii = NIR - SWIR/NIR+SWIR

fun <- function(x) {
       x[is.na(x)] <- 0;
       if (x[37:72] >= x[1:36]){
           0} else {
               ndii <- ((x[1:36]-x[37:72]) / (x[1:36]+x[37:72]));
               silent=TRUE;
               return(ndii)
              }
}
ndii <- calc(raster_stack, fun)
```

The error message is always this one:

> Error in setValues(out, x) : values must be numeric, integer, logical
>   or factor

I added `x[is.na(x)] <- 0` to get rid of the NA value, but it seems that it does not help. Any insights on solving this?

Comment: I think you need to clean up the function.  What is `nd` ? The command `silent = TRUE` will never be executed since it comes after the `return(nd)` line. You might want to check out this link [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. "nd" refers to ndii value that this function is calculating. Any insights? I tried to write for loops but it does not help either.

Comment: @YuyunHe are you sure you can stack binary files that way?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues. Your `if` statement is not good, as you are comparing 36 values. Also, you need to treat the data like a matrix.

```
library(raster)
raster_stack <- stack("NIR.bin", "SWIR.bin")
#ndii = NIR - SWIR/NIR+SWIR

fun <- function(x) {
    y <- (x[,1:36]-x[,37:72]) / (x[,1:36] + x[,37:72])
    i <- x[,37:72] >= x[,1:36]
    y[i] <- 0
    y
}
ndii <- calc(raster_stack, fun)
```